# I already installed an npm library, how do I add it to my package.json dependencies??

Tags: npm

I already installed an npm library. When installing I forgot to add the "-save" flag. How do I add the library to the package.json dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manually add the specific dependency as below:-

example(package.json):-

```
 "react": "^15.6.1"
```

if you don't know the version of the library you're going to install, just do the install again on project path as below:

```
npm i react -S
```

This will add stable version automatically to package.json. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command:

```
npm install react --save
```

or

```
npm install react --save-dev
```